# About proxy man-in-middle attack

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy

I have a website that run under a H2O Proxy, let's call it A server. The backend is WordPress site running with EasyEngine script, let's call it B server.

Now it running like this:

**User** *--(Let's Encrypt SSL)-->* **A (H2O Proxy)** *--(self-signed SSL)-->* **B (nginx backend)**.

I wonder if attackers know my backend's IP address, so can he decrypt or do harmful thing or see what user send to proxy? And how to setup a better strategy?

I have thought to setup Let's Encrypt SSL from A server to B server too. But I think the problem will occur when Let's Encrypt can only renew certificate on A server because the domain is pointing to A's IP address. And the backend (B server) can't renew it.

Found this answer but I don't really know how to do it: https://serverfault.com/a/735977.

Comment: If you can restrict B's access only from A, then I don't see why this would be a issue?

Comment: I have run some website point to B's server without pass the proxy so I don't think restrict connection is good idea.

Comment: The *purpose* of the proxy is to facilitate communication with the backend, which isn't exposed to the Internet. If it *is* exposed to the Internet, you don't need the proxy. So, *don't* expose it to the Internet: put it behind the firewall. Problem solved.

Comment: Let me explain. On my backend running 20+ websites but not relate to each others, and some of them are important that I need to run under a proxy (A server: H2O with Varnish cache). And the others, run directly from backend.

Comment: I found this answer, but I'm not know how to do this: https://serverfault.com/a/735977. `You're creating your certs using your own certificate authority (ca).`, how to do this? Can someone clarify it for me?

Comment: 'Important that I need to run under a proxy' why?

Comment: Varnish make my important websites faster and more stable.

Comment: Thanks for the accept and the bounty!  BTW, in the future, you might want to accept without awarding bounty right away, this way other folks could still see the question in the list of featured ones, and award further points for a good combination of a Q and an accepted A.  (Usually, it's in the last day, just before expiration, that a whole bunch of +1s happens, as folks learn what interesting answers a bounty has gotten.)  Anyhow, +1 goes to you, too! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is to put LetsEncrypt into as many places as possible, possibly facing the issues of not having the desired Fully-Qualified-Domain-Name for the applicable backend on the backend itself in order to get the certificate, especially for automated renewal.

But the whole and only purpose of LetsEncrypt is that it gives you certificates that would expectedly be recognised by all the major browsers, such that the users would not have to manually verify and install your certificate into their respective `cacert.pem`.

But if you just need a secure connection between your own backend and front-end server, then you're not facing the same issue; as such, using LetsEncrypt provides little, if any, extra protections.  What you have to do is use something like [`proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate), together with [`proxy_ssl_verify`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_ssl_verify), both on the front-end, to pin the backend's certificate and/or certificate authority on the front-end, which will be an order of magnitude more secure (due to the pinning) than using LetsEncrypt on the backend.

Comment: Yeah, that what I want. I want more secure between my backend and frontend server. Now my H2O proxy have SSL verify is false, and I don't have any file that call trusted certificate. How can I create it?

Comment: Like just create a Self-signed SSL and put that cert to backend and frontend to verify? If you have a link to detail posts, that's very helpful.

Comment: @AnhTuan, basically, you just have to look through the procedure you've used to create the original certificate for your backend, and find the public files from it, and then use those as a CA file for your front-end H2O proxy.  See http://mdoc.su/o/starttls; basically, just find the public certificate of your backend, and use that as the certificate authority for the front-end proxy (e.g., referenced as `ln -s /etc/ssl/mail.example.com.crt /etc/ssl/CAcert.pem` in the instructions at [`starttls`](http://mdoc.su/o/starttls)).